# Saltstack Result Fails but Jenkins Finished: SUCCESS

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, salt-stack

I try to invoke the below salt script using Jenkins:

```
   create_script:
    file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/broc/import_props.sh
    - source: salt://projects/broc/jboss/files/import.sh.jinja
    - template: jinja

Import_properties:
cmd.script:
- name: /tmp/broc/import.sh
- cwd: /tmp/broc`
```

The Jenkins console output is:

```
`ID: create_script
Function: file.managed
Name: /tmp/broc/import.sh
  Result: True
 Comment: File /tmp/broc/import.sh updated
 Started: 11:31:13.736928
Duration: 166.319 ms
 Changes:   
          ----------
          diff:
              New file
          mode:
              0644

      ID: Import_properties
 Function: cmd.script
    Name: /tmp/broc/import.sh
  Result: False
 Comment: Command '/tmp/broc/import.sh' run
 Started: 11:31:13.903378
 Duration: 399.825 ms
 Changes:   
          ----------
          pid:
              8292
          retcode:
              1`
```

And Jenkins build finished success:

```
`Succeeded: 21 (changed=22)
Failed:     1

Total states run:     22
Total run time:   30.338 s"}}]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS`
```

My question is a saltstack job ID Import_properties Result is False. So a Jenkins build should also finish as FAILURE. In the above case the saltstack result is ignored and build finished SUCCESS. Is there a way the jenkins build be made FAILURE based on saltstack Result?

I see the below Jenkins pipeline:
`try{
    saltCmd = "\"salt -E \"($target)\" \                    state.apply projects.alip.process-server \
                        pillar=\'{\"region\": \"${Region}\",\"siteid\":\"${SiteID}\",\"dbuser\":\"${DBUSER}\",\"dbpass\":\"${DBPASS}\"}\' \""

```
        result = salt authtype: 'pam', 
            clientInterface: local(
                arguments: saltCmd, 
                blockbuild: true, 
                function: 'cmd.run', 
                target: "$my_salttarget",
                saveFile: true,
                targettype: 'glob'),
            credentialsId: "$my_saltcred", 
            servername: "$my_saltserver"
        }
    }catch(e){
        result = e.toString()
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    }finally{
        echo result.replace("\\n",'\n')
    }
}`
```

I am new to Jenkins pipeline script, can you help suggest inputs for adding a post build steps under finally to parse the Jenkins console output, identify a string and if it matches mark the build failure. This is similar to a text finder plugin except that we write a pipeline script.

Comment: would you be able to run wit h`-l debug` in salt to see why its failing?

Comment: The salt failure is due to file permissions on import.sh, correcting permissions and rerunning the job fixes the issue. But the problem is Jenkins failed to finish build as FAILURE after a salt Result False. When a salt Result fails at any job, jenkins should finish as FAILURE.

Comment: You are not showing how you invoke salt from the Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Jenkins invoke a saltstack pipeline script committed on Git repo. Can we add any pipeline stage using try catch?

Answer (score 0):

Even if your state failed, Jenkins believe the salt command it evoked still ran successfully.

Jenkins is not able to detect the errors inside salt itself.
It can only tell if salt runs successfully or not.

This is the same as when you ran salt command line. Even if the state fail, the shell command salt still returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is (as said by others) due to jenkins using the return code if the salt command itself and NOT the return code of the action taken by the state you applied.

My 2 cents here is the

`--retcode-passthrough`

option you can pass to your salt command.

This option allows the salt command return code to match the action taken by the state.

Simply put, if anything fails in a state then the salt command will return a failure return code.

Official doc [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/return_codes/index.html#retcode-passthrough)